# Accessing special files in apache2

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

i want to know how to have access some files in special directory which is need to be authenticate with apache web server 
this is my config file

```
<Directory /var/www/media>
    Order deny,allow
    AuthType            Basic
    AuthName            "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile        htpasswd
    Require user        ABC
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

inside the media folder i have folder named temp and inside temp there are some pdf files
i want to access them without entering password
or access from url like this "www.example.com/media/temp/abc.pdf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `/var/www/media/temp/.htaccess` have these 2 lines:

```
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
```

This will disable `Basic Auth` for whole `/var/www/media/temp/` directory and all files under it. **However if you want to disable only for `/var/www/media/temp/*.pdf` files then you need more code using `mod_setenvif` as this:**

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ NO_AUTH

Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define new rules for subfolder:

```
<Directory /var/www/media/temp>
    Order allow,deny
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```